# Git - The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:

Tags: git

I am using `git version 2.17.1`.

When using I get `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`:

```
root@root-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Code/project git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
Username for 'https://github.com': acc_nt
Password for 'https://acc_nt@github.com': 
From https://github.com/acc_nt/demo_project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        ...
Aborting
```

However, my current settings look like the following:

```
root@root-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Code/project# git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
root@root-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Code/project# git branch
* master
root@root-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Code/project# git stash
No local changes to save
```

Any suggestion how to pull & merge.

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: Those files are tracked in the branch that you are merging, that's what git is trying to tell you.

Comment: What is your use-case? Why do you need the --allow-unrelated-history?

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes, but I cannot push anything to the master branch

Comment: @triplem I simply want to push/pull my files from the master branch, even though they might be the same

Comment: If the files are the same (after a clone) you can just "pull" without any additional parameters. Push willl fetch all changes from the remote repository and merge the changes into your local workspace. If there are no changes, nothing will happen anyways.

Comment: `git status` is not complaining about the untracked files, so those untracked files must also be *ignored* files. The merge action, however, would presumably overwrite those (untracked and ignored) files with new *tracked* files, producing the complaint from `git merge`. If all of these assumptions are true, the solution is simple enough: move (or remove) those untracked files, so that there are no files in the way of the new tracked files.

Answer (score 1):

`--allow-unrelated-histories`  is an option of [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---allow-unrelated-histories) (called by `git pull`), used to merge histories that do not share a common ancestor.

Hopefully, in your case, this should not be needed, considering your local cloned repository and its local `master` branch should have a common history with `origin/master`.
So a simple `git pull` should be enough. Then `git push`.

---

You can use that option when:

- you have created a GitHub repository initialized with a `README`.
- you have create (`git init`) locally a repository with a `README` (and other files)
- you want to push for the first time.

In this case:

- make sure git status is clean
- use:

  ```
    git pull --rebase=merge --allow-unrelated-histories
  ```